# Can I have a stable ip for a virtual machine under VMWare?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, vmware-fusion

I'm using VMWare to emulate Ubuntu on my Leopard MAC OSX.

The ip changes everytime I put the mac in sleep mode.

I was wondering if I can avoid that.

thanks

Comment: it is avoidable in some configurations, need more info on the setup

Comment: the short answer is yes

Comment: @aking1012 what do you need to know in order to give me some istructions how to do it ?

Comment: networking setup....private, nat, bridged, etc.  it is simple with bridged.  you should also be able to configure the vmware ip reservations with nat.  it's about needing more detail on what networks you are connecting to and what your virtual networking setup is.  if any is acceptable there are a bunch of options

Comment: @aking1012 All right, it is NAT. But I can select other options.. so what do I need to do ? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set a static IP on the host just outside of the vmnet nat dhcp scope as discussed here: http://communities.vmware.com/message/1546583?tstart=0